# Why is the pattern is being matched incorrectly to my input?

Tags: html, regex, pattern-matching

The Pattern: 
`^<p .*>&nbsp;</p>$`

The Input: 
`<p style="margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; background-color: #ffffff;" class="MsoNormal">aaa</p><p style="margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; background-color: #ffffff;" class="MsoNormal">&nbsp;</p>`

The entire input is being matched. 
I tried it on: http://regexstorm.net/tester and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular Expressions are generally "greedy". That means that they will match as much as possible.

Your expressing include `.*` which will match any characters 0 or more times. That includes all the `<p>...</p>` which are in the middle.

Also, the expression is trying to match the whole line due to `^...$'` being used.

In essence, your regular expression is matching exactly what you asked it to do: a whole line that starts with `<p` and ends in `>&nbsp;</p>`

If you're looking for a particular section of the string you're searching, you need a better regex

Answer (score 1):

You use a greedy quantifier `.*` that takes as much as it can and then it backtracks to match the rest of the pattern. I your case it matches the whole text and then backtracks to first occurrence of `&nbsp;</p>`.

Btw. you also use `^...$` that forces maching the whole text or nothing.

See the second example in this paragraph: https://medium.com/textmaster-engineering/performance-of-regular-expressions-81371f569698#c8c3